# How to stop a self-built kubernetes cluster

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

Does anyone know the correct procedure to bring down a kubernetes cluster gracefully?
I have K8s 1.12 running on bare metal (built with kubeadm on Ubuntu 16.04) in a lab. I want to bring down the cluster gracefully before I shut down the servers. Strangely this is not documented - so maybe that is handled when the system services are stopped; but I want to check.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The tear down section of the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tear-down) says:

To undo what kubeadm did, you should first drain the node and make sure that the node is empty before shutting it down.

Talking to the master with the appropriate credentials, run:

```
kubectl drain <node name> --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets 
kubectl delete node <node name>
```

Then, on the node being removed, reset all kubeadm installed state:

```
kubeadm reset
```

Comment: Thanks. That is not quite what I am asking. I am not tearing down the cluster. Just stopping it until I want to bring it up again. But yes - I was draining the nodes anyway.

Comment: Oh... sorry for misunderstanding. Well, as i know there is no way to just 'stop' cluster and save it's state and then bring it up. But if you have completely stateless cluster shut down and recreating is equivalent to stopping/starting. Otherwise you'll need to dump your db's and other data. Also for k8s > 1.8 you can type 'kubectl get all --export=true -o yaml' for save all your resources as to yaml file (but you still need to define namespace if it's not default), which gonna help ya to simply bring up your cluster again.

Comment: If you are trying to simulate chaos in the setup make sure you have interesting toolkits handy such as Ark from Heptio which allows you to backup the state of systems and create checkpoint for restoration. 

You may want to simulate chaos after checkpointing by simply deleting namespace and later restoring via Ark.